# Create combinations from two lists and create dictionary with separate key in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, python-itertools

I have two lists
t1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
t2 = ['raising', 'falling', 'constant']

using two lists I want output as follows. with all the possible combinations

```
{
  'regime_1' : {
    'c1' : 'rising',
    'c2' : 'falling',
    'c3' : 'constant'
  },
    'regime_2' : {
    'c1' : 'rising',
    'c2' : 'falling',
    'c3' : 'falling'
  }
}
```

Elements in t1 list should not be repeated inside "regime" key. I have wrote the following code in python.

```
import itertools
t1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
t2 = ['raising', 'faling', 'constant']
combos = [str(i) +":"+ str(n) for i in t1 for n in t2]
combinations = dict(("regime_"+str(i+1),c) for i,c in enumerate(combos))
```

but the out put I get is

```
{'regime_1': 'C1:raising', 'regime_2': 'C1:faling', 'regime_3': 'C1:constant', 'regime_4': 'C2:raising', 'regime_5': 'C2:faling', 'regime_6': 'C2:constant', 'regime_7': 'C3:raising', 'regime_8': 'C3:faling', 'regime_9': 'C3:constant'}
```

Thank you

Comment: How exactly are the combinations generated? Are you looking for the [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of both lists? [Combinations with replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after:

```py
from itertools import product

variables = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
values = ['rising', 'falling', 'constant']

d = {f'regime_{k+1}': dict(v)
     for k, v in enumerate(
        zip(variables, v) for v in product(values, repeat=len(variables))
    )}
print(d)
```

Some explanation:

- `product(values, repeat=len(variables))` gives you the cartesian product of `values`, with the number of repeats equal to the number of variables.
- `zip()` pairs up variables with their generated values.
- By enumerating them, you get the number for the regime together with a set of variables and their values for the `dict` of the regime.
- The f-string takes the number from the enumeration (+1) and creates a key, a dictionary is created from the zip object.

Result:

```py
{
'regime_1': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_2': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_3': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_4': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_5': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_6': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_7': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_8': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_9': {'C1': 'rising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_10': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_11': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_12': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_13': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_14': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_15': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_16': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_17': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_18': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_19': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_20': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_21': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'rising', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_22': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_23': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_24': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'constant'},
'regime_25': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'rising'},
'regime_26': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'falling'},
'regime_27': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'constant'}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import product, zip_longest
t1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3'] 
t2 = ['raising', 'falling', 'constant']
t2 = product(t2,repeat=len(t1))
result = {f"regime_{idx}":dict(zip(*value)) for idx,value in enumerate(zip_longest([t1],t2,fillvalue=t1),1)}
print(result)

{'regime_1': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_2': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_3': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_4': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_5': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_6': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_7': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_8': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_9': {'C1': 'raising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_10': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_11': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_12': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_13': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_14': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_15': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_16': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_17': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_18': {'C1': 'falling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_19': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_20': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_21': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'raising', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_22': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_23': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_24': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'falling', 'C3': 'constant'},
 'regime_25': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'raising'},
 'regime_26': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'falling'},
 'regime_27': {'C1': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C3': 'constant'}}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't include a way to generate the various combinations of values required by OP? (they suggest 'all possible combinations', although it would appear they are really after a product)

Comment: Thank you, I missed that point while reading the question. Corrected now

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import itertools

t1 = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
t2 = ['raising', 'faling', 'constant']

variant=0
return_dict=dict()

for current_tag1 in itertools.product(t2, repeat=len(t2)):
    return_dict['regime_%d' % variant]=dict(zip(t1,current_tag1))
    variant+=1

print return_dict
```

output

```
{
'regime_18': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_19': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_16': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_17': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_14': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_15': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_12': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_13': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_10': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_11': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_4': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_5': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_6': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_7': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_0': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_1': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_2': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_3': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_8': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'raising'},
'regime_9': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'faling'},
'regime_23': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_22': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_21': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'faling', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_20': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'raising', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_26': {'C3': 'constant', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_25': {'C3': 'faling', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'constant'},
'regime_24': {'C3': 'raising', 'C2': 'constant', 'C1': 'constant'}
}
```

Comment: Permutations won't include repeating values, but OP's example does contain these.